# Downloading pretrained TimeNet RNN?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I've been looking for the pretrained net behind [TimeNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.08838) - a resnet equivalent for time series analysis via RNNs.

There's some articles and several publications of the same paper, but the weights and architecture themselves are not easy to find.

Anyone knows how to find it? Is it available to the public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like someone answered this on the top response to this Quora question.

[Why are there no pre-trained RNN models](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-there-no-pre-trained-RNN-models)

It's not available to the public just yet.